# how to pass 2D array type char (string) as function parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, 2d

i can't compile the program. is there anything wrong with my function parameter? is it because of my array declaration(char category[SIZE][15])? I've made it as 2D array since column part holds the size of the alphabet. could you guys point out what is wrong with my code and how to pass the array as the function parameter? i'm sorry i'm completely new on this topic.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
const int COLSIZE=3;
const int NAMESIZE=30;
void inputPersonalData(int, long[],int,char[],float[],float[]);
void calcBMI(int,float[],float[],float[]);
void bmiCategory(int,float[],char[]);
void displayPersonalData(int,long[],char[],float[],float[],float[],char[]);
void inputCal(int,char[],long[],float[][COLSIZE],char[]);
int main()
{
    int SIZE;
    long ID[SIZE];
    char name[NAMESIZE];
    float weight[SIZE];
    float height[SIZE];
    float BMI[SIZE];
    char category[SIZE][15];
    char meal[COLSIZE][10];
    float calIntake[SIZE][COLSIZE];

    cout<<"Enter the number of models: ";
    cin>>SIZE;

    inputPersonalData(SIZE,ID,NAMESIZE,name,weight,height);
    calcBMI(SIZE,weight,height,BMI);
    bmiCategory(SIZE,BMI,category);
    displayPersonalData(SIZE,ID,name,weight,height,BMI,category);

    strcpy(meal[0],"BREAKFAST");
    strcpy(meal[1],"LUNCH");
    strcpy(meal[2],"DINNER");
    inputCal(SIZE,name,ID,calIntake,meal);

    return 0;
}
void inputPersonalData(int rowSize, long id[],int nameSize, char nama[],float berat[],float tinggi[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<rowSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nModel "<<i+1<<"'s information\n\n";
        cout<<"ID: ";
        cin>>id[i];
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>>ws;
        cin.getline(nama,nameSize);
        cout<<"Weight in kg: ";
        cin>>berat[i];
        cout<<"Height in m: ";
        cin>>tinggi[i];
        cout<<endl<<"***************************************"<<endl;
    }
}
void calcBMI(int rowSize,float berat[],float tinggi[],float bmi[])
{

    for(int j=0;j<rowSize;j++)
    {
        bmi[j]=(berat[j]/tinggi[j])/tinggi[j];
    }

}
void bmiCategory(int rowSize,float bmi[],char category[])
{
    for(int k=0;k<rowSize;k++)
    {
        if(bmi[k]>25)
            strcpy(category[k],"OVERWEIGHT");
        else if(bmi[k]>18)
            strcpy(category[k],"NORMAL");
        else
            strcpy(category[k],"UNDERWEIGHT");
    }
}
void inputCal(int rowSize,char nama[],long id[],float calorie[][COLSIZE],char mealName[])
{
    for(int row=0;row<rowSize;row++)
    {
        cout<<"Model "<<row+1<<" ("<<nama[row]<<", ID: )"<<id[row]<<" DAILY CALORIE INTAKE:\n";
        for(int col=0;col<COLSIZE;col++)
        {
            cout<<"Calorie intake for "<<mealName[col]<<": ";
            calorie[row][col];
        }
    }
}
void displayPersonalData(int rowSize,long id[],char nama[],float berat[],float tinggi[],float bmi[],char category[])
{
    cout<<"No.\tID\tName\t\t\tWeight(kg)\tHeight(m)\tBMI\tCategory\n";
    for(int m=0;m<rowSize;m++)
    {
        cout<<m+1<<"\t"<<id[m]<<"\t"<<nama[m]<<"\t"<<berat[m]<<"\t"<<tinggi[m]<<"\t"<<bmi[m]<<"\t"<<category[m]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because you have a local variable with the same name `bmiCategory `.

Comment: oohhhh okay2 thank you sir

Comment: First you declare your arrays of undefined SIZE then you take the SIZE over input, not to mention this method requires extension

Comment: i have no problem with the undefined SIZE since i can compile other parts of my code which related to the undefined SIZE until i include the 2D array type char function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing 2D arrays to functions in a correct way. Read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more details. By the way, here is your code with some modifications:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
const int COLSIZE=3;
const int NAMESIZE=30;
void inputPersonalData(int, long[],int,char[],float[],float[]);
void calcBMI(int,float[],float[],float[]);
void bmiCategory(int,float[],char[][15]);
void displayPersonalData(int,long[],char[],float[],float[],float[],char[][15]);
void inputCal(int,char[],long[],float[][COLSIZE],char[][10]);
int main()
{
    int SIZE;
    long ID[SIZE];
    char name[NAMESIZE];
    float weight[SIZE];
    float height[SIZE];
    float BMI[SIZE];
    char category[SIZE][15];
    char meal[COLSIZE][10];
    float calIntake[SIZE][COLSIZE];

    cout<<"Enter the number of models: ";
    cin>>SIZE;

    inputPersonalData(SIZE,ID,NAMESIZE,name,weight,height);
    calcBMI(SIZE,weight,height,BMI);
    bmiCategory(SIZE,BMI,category);
    displayPersonalData(SIZE,ID,name,weight,height,BMI,category);

    strcpy(meal[0],"BREAKFAST");
    strcpy(meal[1],"LUNCH");
    strcpy(meal[2],"DINNER");
    inputCal(SIZE,name,ID,calIntake,meal);

    return 0;
}
void inputPersonalData(int rowSize, long id[],int nameSize, char nama[],float berat[],float tinggi[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<rowSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nModel "<<i+1<<"'s information\n\n";
        cout<<"ID: ";
        cin>>id[i];
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>>ws;
        cin.getline(nama,nameSize);
        cout<<"Weight in kg: ";
        cin>>berat[i];
        cout<<"Height in m: ";
        cin>>tinggi[i];
        cout<<endl<<"***************************************"<<endl;
    }
}
void calcBMI(int rowSize,float berat[],float tinggi[],float bmi[])
{

    for(int j=0;j<rowSize;j++)
    {
        bmi[j]=(berat[j]/tinggi[j])/tinggi[j];
    }

}
void bmiCategory(int rowSize,float bmi[],char category[][15])
{
    for(int k=0;k<rowSize;k++)
    {
        if(bmi[k]>25)
            strcpy(category[k],"OVERWEIGHT");
        else if(bmi[k]>18)
            strcpy(category[k],"NORMAL");
        else
            strcpy(category[k],"UNDERWEIGHT");
    }
}
void inputCal(int rowSize,char nama[],long id[],float calorie[][COLSIZE],char mealName[][10])
{
    for(int row=0;row<rowSize;row++)
    {
        cout<<"Model "<<row+1<<" ("<<nama[row]<<", ID: )"<<id[row]<<" DAILY CALORIE INTAKE:\n";
        for(int col=0;col<COLSIZE;col++)
        {
            cout<<"Calorie intake for "<<mealName[col]<<": ";
            calorie[row][col];
        }
    }
}
void displayPersonalData(int rowSize,long id[],char nama[],float berat[],float tinggi[],float bmi[],char category[][15])
{
    cout<<"No.\tID\tName\t\t\tWeight(kg)\tHeight(m)\tBMI\tCategory\n";
    for(int m=0;m<rowSize;m++)
    {
        cout<<m+1<<"\t"<<id[m]<<"\t"<<nama[m]<<"\t"<<berat[m]<<"\t"<<tinggi[m]<<"\t"<<bmi[m]<<"\t"<<category[m]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your link and the modifications. now i have to fix the other parts too. anyway, thank you so much Ali.

Answer (score 0):

fixed

```css
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int COLSIZE=3;
const int SIZE=15;
const int NAMESIZE=30;
void inputPersonalData(int, long[],char[][NAMESIZE],float[],float[]);
void calcBMI(int,float[],float[],float[]);
void bmiCategory(int,float[],char[][15]);
void displayPersonalData(int,long[],char[][NAMESIZE],float[],float[],float[],char[][15]);
void inputCal(int,char[][NAMESIZE],long[],float[][COLSIZE],char[][10]);
void totalCal(int,float[][COLSIZE],float[]);
void idealCal(int rowSize,float bmi[],float idealCal[]);
void condition(int,float [],float [],long [],char[][NAMESIZE]);
void searchId(int,long[],char[][NAMESIZE],float[],float[],float[],char[][15]);
int main()
{
    int numdata;
    long ID[SIZE];
    char name[SIZE][NAMESIZE];
    float weight[SIZE];
    float height[SIZE];
    float BMI[SIZE];
    char category[SIZE][15];
    char meal[COLSIZE][10];
    float calIntake[SIZE][COLSIZE];
    float totalCalIntake[SIZE];
    float idealCalIntake[SIZE];

    cout<<"Enter the number of models: ";
    cin>>numdata; //assume user input lower than size

    inputPersonalData(numdata,ID,name,weight,height);
    calcBMI(numdata,weight,height,BMI);
    bmiCategory(numdata,BMI,category);
    displayPersonalData(numdata,ID,name,weight,height,BMI,category);

    strcpy(meal[0],"BREAKFAST");
    strcpy(meal[1],"LUNCH");
    strcpy(meal[2],"DINNER");
    cout<<"\nDAILY CALORIE INTAKE for:\n";
    inputCal(numdata,name,ID,calIntake,meal);
    totalCal(numdata,calIntake,totalCalIntake);
    idealCal(numdata,BMI,idealCalIntake);
    condition(numdata,totalCalIntake,idealCalIntake,ID,name);
    searchId(numdata,ID,name,weight,height,BMI,category);

    return 0;
}
void inputPersonalData(int rowSize, long id[], char nama[][NAMESIZE],float berat[],float tinggi[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<rowSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nModel "<<i+1<<"'s information\n\n";
        cout<<"ID: ";
        cin>>id[i];
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>>ws;
        cin.getline(nama[i],NAMESIZE);
        cout<<"Weight in kg: ";
        cin>>berat[i];
        cout<<"Height in m: ";
        cin>>tinggi[i];
        cout<<endl<<"***************************************"<<endl;
    }
}
void calcBMI(int rowSize,float berat[],float tinggi[],float bmi[])
{

    for(int j=0;j<rowSize;j++)
    {
        bmi[j]=(berat[j]/tinggi[j])/tinggi[j];
    }

}
void bmiCategory(int rowSize,float bmi[],char category[][15])
{
    for(int k=0;k<rowSize;k++)
    {
        if(bmi[k]>25.0)
            strcpy(category[k],"OVERWEIGHT");
        else if(bmi[k]>18.0)
            strcpy(category[k],"NORMAL");
        else
            strcpy(category[k],"UNDERWEIGHT");
    }
}
void displayPersonalData(int rowSize,long id[],char nama[][NAMESIZE],float berat[],float tinggi[],float bmi[],char category[][15])
{
 cout<<"\n****************************************************************************************************************\n";
    cout<<"No.\tID\tName\t\t\tWeight(kg)\tHeight(m)\tBMI\t\tCategory\n";
    for(int m=0;m<rowSize;m++)
    {
        cout<<m+1<<"\t"<<id[m]<<"\t"<<nama[m]<<"\t\t"<<berat[m]<<"\t\t"<<tinggi[m]<<"\t\t"<<bmi[m]<<"\t\t"<<category[m]<<endl;
    }
}
void inputCal(int rowSize,char nama[][NAMESIZE],long id[],float calorie[][COLSIZE],char mealName[][10])
{
    for(int row=0;row<rowSize;row++)
    {
        cout<<"\nModel "<<row+1<<" ("<<nama[row]<<", ID: "<<id[row]<<") \n";
        for(int col=0;col<COLSIZE;col++)
        {
            cout<<"Calorie intake for "<<mealName[col]<<": ";
            cin>>calorie[row][col];
        }
    }
}
void totalCal(int rowSize,float calorie[][COLSIZE],float totalCalorie[])
{
 for(int p=0;p<rowSize;p++)
 {
  totalCalorie[p]=0;
  for(int q=0;q<COLSIZE;q++)
  {
   totalCalorie[p]=totalCalorie[p]+calorie[p][q];
  }
 }
}
void idealCal(int rowSize,float bmi[],float idealCal[])
{
 for(int n=0;n<rowSize;n++)
 {
  if(bmi[n]>25.0)
  {
   idealCal[n]=1500;
  }
  else if(bmi[n]>18.0)
  {
   idealCal[n]=2000;
  }
  else
  {
   idealCal[n]=2500;
  }
 }
}
void condition(int rowSize,float totalCalorie[],float idealCal[],long id[],char nama[][NAMESIZE])
{
 float minuteXercise[rowSize];
 for(int r=0;r<rowSize;r++)
 {
  if(totalCalorie[r]>idealCal[r])
  {
   minuteXercise[r]=(totalCalorie[r]-idealCal[r])/15.95;
   cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
   cout<<"\nModel "<<r+1<<" Id: "<<id[r]<<" ("<<nama[r]<<") need to excercise for "<<minuteXercise[r]<<" minutes to burn excess calorie.\n";
  }
  else if(totalCalorie[r]<idealCal[r])
  {
   cout<<"\nModel "<<r+1<<" Id: "<<id[r]<<" ("<<nama[r]<<") need to add "<<idealCal[r]-totalCalorie[r]<<" more calories to gain more weight.\n";
  }
  else
  {
   cout<<"\nModel "<<r+1<<" Id: "<<id[r]<<" ("<<nama[r]<<")'s calorie intake are perfect.\n";
  }
 }
}
void searchId(int rowSize,long id[],char nama[][NAMESIZE],float berat[],float tinggi[],float bmi[],char category[][15])
{
 long searchModel;
 bool foundId=false;
 cout<<"\nEnter ID to be search: ";
 cin>>searchModel;
 for(int s=0;s<rowSize;s++)
 {
  if(searchModel==id[s])
  {
   foundId=true;
   cout<<"\n****************************************************************************************************************\n";
      cout<<"No.\tID\tName\t\t\tWeight(kg)\tHeight(m)\tBMI\t\tCategory\n";
      cout<<s+1<<"\t"<<id[s]<<"\t"<<nama[s]<<"\t\t"<<berat[s]<<"\t\t"<<tinggi[s]<<"\t\t"<<bmi[s]<<"\t\t"<<category[s]<<endl;
  }
 }
 while(!foundId)
 {
  cout<<"\nThe ID is not in our system!\n";
  cout<<"Enter ID to be search: ";
  cin>>searchModel;
  for(int s=0;s<rowSize;s++)
  {
   if(searchModel==id[s])
   {
    foundId=true;
    cout<<"\n****************************************************************************************************************\n";
       cout<<"No.\tID\tName\t\t\tWeight(kg)\tHeight(m)\tBMI\t\tCategory\n";
       cout<<s+1<<"\t"<<id[s]<<"\t"<<nama[s]<<"\t\t"<<berat[s]<<"\t\t"<<tinggi[s]<<"\t\t"<<bmi[s]<<"\t\t"<<category[s]<<endl;
   }
  }
 }
}
```